# SQL Server 2008 - Inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, inner-join

Good morning,

I use SQL Server 2008 and I have 2 tables that I join on App#

Structure of T2 is and it has the following values:

```
App #   code
---------------    
123     8
123     16
123     32
124     16
125     8
125     16
```

I need to print only applications that have a code of 16.  My code is as follows:

```
Select appID, Code from T1
Inner join T2 on
T1.AppID = T2.AppID and Code = 16
```

However I get a result including app# 123, 124 and 125, but I need only 124 to show (I need to extract only apps that have code of 16 and not something else.)

Thanks for your help
Joe

Comment: Why do you expect not to get 123 and 125? Those also have records with `Code = 16`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It appears Joe wants only wants Apps which have a row with a code of 16, and no other rows for the same App.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT T1.appID
FROM T1
  JOIN T2
    ON  T2.AppID = T1.AppID 
    AND T2.Code = 16
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM T2 
        WHERE T2.AppID = T1.AppID 
          AND T2.Code <> 16
      ) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

This should also work; Here is [Sql-Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/010c4/5)

```
select T2.appId,code
from T2 join T1 on T2.appId = T1.appId
where code = 16 and 
    T2.appId not in (select appId from T2 where code != 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the condition in where

```
select appId, code from (
    select T2.appId, code, count(*) over (partition by T2.appId) CNT
    from T2 join T1 on T2.appId = T1.appId
    where code=16 
)x where CNT=1
```

or the same can be done using having

```
select 
    T2.appId, code
from T2 join T1 on T2.appId = T1.appId
where code=16 
group by T2.appId, code
having count(T2.appID)=1
```

Comment: That will have the same result in this specific case

Answer (score -1):

The condtion on a select statment is **where** not **AND**

**TRY THIS ONE**

```
Select appID, Code from T1
Inner join T2 on
T1.AppID = T2.AppID
where t1.code=16
```

Comment: Actually, this query is 100% equivalent to the OP's query.

Comment: @ypercube: It is simple yet this won't work due to multipart identifier issue in the Select `appID`.

Comment: @Joe if this have Worked For you how about marking it as an answer :)

Comment: @Kaf You are right of course (but the multipart identifier issue is in the OP's query, too). And `Code` is in `T2` table so this won't work anyway, as it is.

Comment: I will test it and definitely post it as an answer if it works. Thanks a lot.